# CSV file from excel will not work with program?

Tags: python

My program will not run, it return an error of...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/nasa missions apllication.py", line 16, in <module>
nasa = find_details(lookup_id)
File "C:/Python33/nasa missions apllication.py", line 4, in find_details
nasa_f= open("nasa_missions.csv")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nasa_missions.csv'
```

and here is my program...

```
import csv

def find_details(lookup_id):
   nasa_f= open("nasa_missions.csv")
   for each_line in nasa_f:
      z = {} 
      (z['e'], z['f'], z['g'], z['h'], z['i']) = each_line.split(",")
      if lookup_id == int(z['a']):
         nasa_f.close()
         return(z)
   nasa_f.close()
   print("This nasa space mission is not in the database")
   return({})

lookup_id = int(input("Enter the id for most succesful nasa space missions: "))   
nasa = find_details(lookup_id)

if nasa:
    print("Index:     " + nasa['e'])
    print("Mission:   " + nasa['f'])
    print("Luanch:    " + nasa['g'])
    print("Status:    " + nasa['h'])
    print("Scientific Objectives for Space:       " + nasa['i'])
```

The CSV file for some reason will not open from excel?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to do with Excel, or the format of the file; Python is trying to open the file:

```
nasa_f= open("nasa_missions.csv")
```

but simply cannot find it. Where on your computer is `nasa_missions.csv` stored? Frankly, the easiest thing here is to copy or move the file to `C:/Python33/`.

Also, note that you should generally access files as follows:

```
with open("nasa_missions.csv") as nasa_f:
    # use the file here
# file is automatically closed when you leave the with block
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/nasa apllication.py", line 16, in <module>
    nasa = find_details(lookup_id)
  File "C:/Python33/nasa apllication.py", line 7, in find_details
    (z['e'],z['f'],z['g'],z['h'],z['i']) = each_line.split(",")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)

Comment: Splitting the line by `","` is giving more than 5 items; you can limit the split to deal with this, and have an extra item to unpack to: `z['e'], z['f'], z['g'], z['h'], z['i'], _ = each_line.split(",", 5)`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/nasa apllication.py", line 16, in <module>
    nasa = find_details(lookup_id)
  File "C:/Python33/nasa apllication.py", line 7, in find_details
    z['e'],z['f'],z['g'],z['h'],z['i'], _ = each_line.split(",",5)
ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack

Comment: It would appear that the lines in your file have different lengths. You will need to deal with this, e.g. `temp = each_line.split(",")` followed by `if len(temp) >= 5:`. Please do not add more new errors in the comments, that is not an appropriate way to develop software.

Answer (score 1):

It means python could not find the path to the file.

You can use `os.chdir(dir)` to change to the directory of the file "nasa_missions.csv".